# Grails Multiple Select for One-to-many

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm in Grails 2.0.4
I'm getting the error:

No signature of method: com.example.User.addToDefaultStorePricingProfiles() is applicable for argument types: (com.example.PricingProfile) values: [com.example.PricingProfile : 5] on the bindData() line. Do I have to save the User and Store first before adding the already-persisted PricingProfiles, or is there a better way to do this?

Models

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    Store defaultStore

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [orders: Order]
}

class Store {

  String storeNumber
  String name
  PricingProfile defaultPricingProfile

  static belongsTo = [retailer: Retailer]

  static hasMany = [pricingProfiles: PricingProfile]
}

class PricingProfile {

  String name

  static belongsTo = [retailer: Retailer]
}
```

I'm using a multiple select in the view for pricingProfiles on the Store

```
<g:select from="${retailer.pricingProfiles}" name="defaultStore.pricingProfiles" value="${user?.defaultStore?.pricingProfiles*.id}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" class="pricingProfiles" />
```

Store Controller

```
def save() {
    Retailer retailer = Retailer.get(params.retailer)
    User user = new User()
    user.defaultStore = new Store()

    bindData(user, params)

    user.validate()
    user.defaultStore.validate()

    if (user.hasErrors() || user.defaultStore.hasErrors()) {
        log.error("Error saving store: ${user.errors.fieldErrors} ${user.defaultStore.errors.fieldErrors}")
        flash.storeError = "Please correct the errors below"
        render(view: 'create')
    } else {
        retailer.addToStores(user.defaultStore)
        retailer.addToUsers(user)
        retailer.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        flash.confirm = "Store ${user.defaultStore.storeNumber} successfully added"
        redirect (action: 'list', params: [retailer: retailer.id])
    }
}
```

params:

```
defaultStore.pricingProfiles: 2
defaultStore.pricingProfiles: 3
defaultStore.pricingProfiles: 4
defaultStore.defaultPricingProfile.id: 2
retailer: 2
submitStore: Save
defaultStore.storeNumber: 888
username: wert
password: wert
defaultStore.name: Fake Store
```

Comment: What does your User domain look like?

Comment: The problem is with the `user`, maybe, somewhere in your gsp you have an input or, most probably, a select with a name that overlaps with a property of the User class. Do you know what `params` are being sent and can you paste the User class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add the pricingProfiles manually.

```
<g:select from="${retailer.pricingProfiles}" name="pricingProfiles" value="${user?.defaultStore?.pricingProfiles*.id}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" class="pricingProfiles" />
```

Then in the controller,

```
params.pricingProfiles.each {
    PricingProfile pricingProfile = PricingProfile.get(it)
    user.defaultStore.addToPricingProfiles(pricingProfile)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you first need to create a `Store` for the `User.defaultStore` property before trying to bind everything to a `User`

It seems that Grails cannot do that automatically for you.
Given that `Store` and `User` have properties with different names you can do the following:

1. Remove the `defaultStore.` from the params that have it.
2. Create the objects like this:

   ```
   Store defaultStore = new Store(params)
   User user = new User(params)
   user.defaultStore = defaultStore
   ```